# Core Data not saving the relationship

Tags: swift, core-data

Hi I have another issue with core data, i am trying to save an entity called Date which has a relationship one - one with another entity called Folder.

[image]

The following is the code of how I save the entity Date:

```
if(occasion == nil){
    occasion = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Date", inManagedObjectContext: handler.context!) as? Date
}

formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

occasion?.title = textFieldTitle.text
occasion?.date = formatter.dateFromString(textfieldDate.text)!
occasion?.occasion = textfieldOccasion.text
occasion?.notify = switchNotifyMe.on
occasion?.folder = folder!

handler.context?.save(&error)
```

When I debug this is what I see:
[image]

But when I do the following code to list all the Dates that belong to a specific folder I get 1; this is the code to get all the Dates that are related to a specific folder:

```
var error: NSError?
var name: String = (folder?.name)!

var filter = NSPredicate(format: " folder.name = %@",name)
var handler: HACoreDataHandler = HACoreDataHandler()
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Date")

request.predicate = filter
dates = handler.context?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [Date]
```

If I remove the NSPredicate I do get all the dates and that is because the property folder = nil.

Any Idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each `Folder` can have many `Dates`, you need to set the `dates` relationship to be "to many".

When you set the `Date` object's `folder` property, CoreData sets the corresponding inverse relationship, ie. setting the `Folder` object's `dates` property.  Because you have defined this as "to one", CoreData has to remove any existing `Date` for that folder.  Hence the `folder` property for that existing `Date` is set to nil (which is what your fetch shows).

If you redefine the relationship as "to many", CoreData will use an NSSet for the `dates` property, so it can keep track of several different `Dates` for the same `Folder`.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, I thought I did that way but when I went back to the model in the Folder Entity I found the relationship was also one to one.